# Creating adjacent files in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I create a file adjacent to the one I'm editing in Vim? If I'm editing ./app/lib/foo.js I want to create ./app/lib/bar.js

Answer (score 2):

Given the information on [the VIM wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file):

```
:e %:p:h/myNewFile.txt
```

Comment: I think the last solution must the preferred way as you in most situations don't want to change your working directory.

Comment: @tidbeck You're right, I removed that part from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the new file is easy to type, Oliver Salzburg's answer is probably best. If the name of the new file differs only slightly from the name of the current file, it may be easier to use

```
:e ^R%
```

where `^R` is `Ctrl-R`. `^R%` will be expanded immediately to the name of the current file. Then you can edit that name and change it to the name of the new file. See

```
:help c_CTRL-R
```

Answer (score 0):

Just "open" the new file as if it already existed, like so:

```
vim ./app/lib/bar.js
```

Or, if bar.js is going to be very similar to foo.js, you could copy foo.js into bar.js like so:

```
cp ./app/lib/foo.js ./app/lib/bar.js
```

To create an empty foo.js file, just "touch" it like this:

```
touch ./app/lib/foo.js
```

Comment: I think the question was about doing this inside vim so maybe you should add some information about how you can run this external commands using `:!this_is_thecommand`

Answer (score 0):

One way I like to create files is using the *Explore window*.

Open the Explore window:

```
:E
```

Now to create a new file in the current directory press <kbd>%</kbd>, it will ask for a file name and then open the new file (actually the file will not be created until you write it).